# Parse error when reading

Tags: parsing, haskell, ghc

GHC can't derive `Read` or `Show` for complicated GADTs, so I attempted to define custom instances below that satisfy `read . show == id`. I've simplified the example as much as possible (while still triggering the runtime error like my real code). I decided to let GHC do the heavy lifting of writing `Read` and `Show` instances by making `newtype` wrappers for each GADT constructor (more accurately: for each *type* output by the GADT). In the `Read`/`Show` instances, I simply read/show the newtype wrapper and convert where necessary. I assumed this was foolproof: I'm letting GHC define all of the non-trivial instances. However, I seem to have done something wrong.

In my real code, `Foo` below is a complicated GADT that GHC won't derive `Show` or `Read` for. Since `Foo` is a wrapper (in part) around a newtype, I use the derived `Show`/`Read` instances for that.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Text.Read (Read(readPrec))

newtype Bar r = Bar r deriving (Show, Read)
newtype Foo r = Foo (Bar r)
-- use the GHC-derived Show/Read for Bar
instance (Show r) => Show (Foo r) where
  show (Foo x) = show x
instance (Read r) => Read (Foo r) where
  readPrec = Foo <$> readPrec
```

This instance seems to work: I can call `read . show` and I get back the input.
Now I have a wrapper around `Foo`:

```
data U t rep r where
  U1  :: t r -> U t Int r
  U2 :: t r -> U t Char r
-- use the Read/Show instances for U1Wrap and U2Wrap
newtype U1Wrap t r = U1Wrap {unU1Wrap :: t r} deriving (Show, Read)
newtype U2Wrap t r = U2Wrap (t r) deriving (Show, Read)
instance (Read (t r)) => Read (U t Int r) where
  readPrec = (U1 . unU1Wrap) <$> readPrec
instance (Read (U2Wrap t r)) => Read (U t Char r) where
  readPrec = do
    x <- readPrec
    return $ case x of
      (U2Wrap y) -> U2 y
instance (Show (t r)) => Show (U t Int r) where
  show (U1 x) = show $ U1Wrap x
instance (Show (t r)) => Show (U t Char r) where
  show (U2 x) = show (U2Wrap x :: U2Wrap t r)
```

Like `Foo`, `U` is a complicated GADT, so I define custom newtype wrappers for each output type of the GADT. Unfortunately, my `Show`/`Read` instances don't work:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = U1 $ Foo $ Bar 3
      y = U2 $ Foo $ Bar 3
  print $ show (read (show x) `asTypeOf` x)
  print $ show (read (show y) `asTypeOf` y)
```

`main` prints the first line, but I get `Exception: Prelude.read: no parse` on the second line.

This is my first time using `Read`, so I suspect I'm doing something incorrectly, though I don't see what that is.

My questions are:

1. Why am I getting this error, and *logically* how can I fix it? (There are several ways to poke the minimal example above to make the error go away, but I can't do those things in my real code.)
2. Is there a different/better high-level approach to `Read`ing GADTs?

Comment: What happens if you use `deriving instance Read (t r) => Read (U t rep r)`? Is that not accepted? Would life be easier if you defined your GADT to have only two parameters, `tr` and `rep`, and defined a newtype around it to combine `t` with `r`?

Comment: @dfeuer I don't think that works in my example, but even if it does, it definitely doesn't work in my real code.

Comment: I actually meant `Show`, not `Read`. `Show` is much easier to derive.

Comment: @dfeuer Since my `Read` instance has to be manually derived, I figure I have to have a corresponding `Show` instance, which is certainly not what GHC would generate (even if it could).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom `Show` instance for `Foo` doesn't parenthesize correctly.

```
> U2 $ Foo $ Bar 3
U2Wrap Bar 3
```

When writing custom `Show` instances, you should define `showsPrec` instead. That's because `show` just gives back a string independently of the context, while `showsPrec` parenthesizes based on precendence. See [`Text.Show`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.8.2.0/Text-Show.html) for further documentation.

```
instance (Show r) => Show (Foo r) where
 showsPrec n (Foo x) = showsPrec n x
```

Which works here.

I don't know of an elegant approach that would automacially get us a `Read` instance for this `GADT`. The deriving mechanism can't seem to figure out that only a single constructor has to be considered for each `rep`.

At least `Show` can be derived even here. I also include here a manual `Read` instance  which I hope conforms to `Show`. I tried to mimic the definitions in [`Text.Read`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.8.2.0/Text-Read.html), which you could also do in other cases. Alternatively, one could use the `-ddump-deriv` GHC argument to look at derived `Read` instances, and try to copy them in custom code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, StandaloneDeriving, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Text.Read
import Data.Proxy

data U t rep r where
  U1 :: t r -> U t Int r
  U2 :: t r -> U t Char r

deriving instance Show (t r) => Show (U t rep r)

instance Read (t r) => Read (U t Int r) where
  readPrec = parens $ do
    prec 10 $ do
      Ident "U1" <- lexP
      U1 <$> readPrec

instance Read (t r) => Read (U t Char r) where
  readPrec = parens $ do
    prec 10 $ do
      Ident "U2" <- lexP
      U2 <$> readPrec
```

Comment: I'm looking for some intuition. *Why* should I define `showsPrec` instead of `show`? Regarding the derived `Show` instance, my `U` type is too complicated for GHC to derive an instance, which is why I'm doing it by hand.

Comment: I added some links and explanation.